# Mapping json data in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm having a hard time mapping data children to a table. What you see in my json data below is an example of one item. I have a map in the Card component (See the render function content) to display as many items as I have independently in a MaterialUI Card. And Each card has also a table. I am mapping the table content with the children (rows) in each item. Because not every item has the same amount of data or same data.

My Cards are being populated just fine with the image, page, and section. But my rows content are not being populated in the table rows (TableRowColumn)

Here is the simplified json with one item:

```
exports.administration = [
    {
        id:'1',
        image: '/assets/images/media/christopher-walken.jpg',
        page: '',
        section: 'Test one',
        rows: [
            {
                id:'1.1',
                type: 'STRING',
                name: 'Page1Var1',
                description:'n/a',
                show:'Both',
                label: 'Page1Var1',
                value: 'Test one',
                presentation: 'n/a',
                lines: '1',
                characters: '4096',
            },
        ],

    },
]
```

The database declaration and call

```
const TEMPLATEITEMS = require('data/templates.js');
const administrationData = TEMPLATEITEMS['administration'];
```

In my render function:

```
{administrationData.map((row, index) => (
    <Card key={index}>
        <CardText>
            <div> 
                 //these are working fine
                 <h4>{row.page} / {row.section}</h4> 
                 <img src={row.image} alt={row.name} /> 
            </div> 
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                    //these are not working. I tried several variations as you see below
                    <TableRow id={row.rows.id}>
                        <TableRowColumn> {row.type} </TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn> {row[index].rows.name} </TableRowColumn>
                        ...
                        <TableRowColumn> {rows.characters} </TableRowColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </CardText>
    </Card>         
))}
```

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{administrationData.map((row, index) => (
    <Card key={index}>
    <CardText>
        <div>
             <h4>{row.page} / {row.section}</h4> 
             <img style={styles.image} src={row.image} alt={row.name} /> 
        </div> 
        <Table>
            <TableBody>
                {
                    row.rows.map((item, itemIndex)=>{
                       return(
                           <TableRow id={item.rows.id} index={itemIndex}>
                               <TableRowColumn> {item.type} </TableRowColumn>
                               <TableRowColumn> {item.name}</TableRowColumn>
                               ...
                               <TableRowColumn> {item.characters}</TableRowColumn>
                           </TableRow>
                       );
                    })
                } 
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </CardText>
  </Card>         
))}
```

Comment: Nice! This one worked with one other modification you didn't mention in your answer but it was easy to figure out. The items must use `item` instead of `row`. So this `{item.type}` instead of `{row.type}`

Comment: some confusion dude

Comment: Yeah, I edited it as well for cleanliness so that anyone else that comes across this answer can understand it as well. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

```
const tableRows = (row) => (
 row.rows.map((r, ix) => <TableRow id={r.id}>
    <TableRowColumn> {r.type} </TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn> {r.name} </TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn> {r.characters} </TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
    )
)
```

and then:

```
<TableBody> {tableRows(row)} </TableBody>
```

Untested, but hopefully not too far off.

Comment: It is not too far but it didn't work because the rows are undefined outside of the parent mapping it. But I do like your const isolation

Comment: It's effectively the same as the proposed answer without embedding it. I think my naming was a bit off too!

Comment: I ended up isolating it as you proposed here. So in essence this should the accepted answer, but I had already given it to someone else who gave a full working solution and I feel bad taking it away from him. Besides, he can use the rep points ;) I'm sure other visitors will credit your answer Thanks Ric!

Comment: haha! It's ok, it's not all about the points, but helping out. Good you got it working.